# Using GetMouseMovePointsEx and other Windows API function on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, winapi

I haven't learned yet how to correctly convert the Windows API functions to be used on Excel VBA. If I can't find it online and it isn't something easy like [SwapMouseButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646264(v=vs.85).aspx) or [SetDoubleClickTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646263(v=vs.85).aspx) I just get stuck on getting it to work.

Can I get some help fixing my call of the [GetMouseMovePointsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646259(v=vs.85).aspx) function and maybe tips to understand better how to do it for other complex function?

Here's what I have in a module:

```
Private Declare Function SwapMouseButton Lib "user32" (ByVal fSwap As Boolean) As Boolean
Private Declare Function SetDoubleClickTime Lib "user32" (ByVal uInterval As Integer) As Boolean
Private Type MOUSEMOVEPOINT
  x As Integer
  y As Integer
  time As Long
  dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
'Private Declare Function WindowProc Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Const WM_MOUSEDOWN = &H200
Private Declare Function GetMouseMovePointsEx Lib "user32" (ByVal cbSize As Integer, ByRef lppt As MOUSEMOVEPOINT, ByRef lpptBuf() As MOUSEMOVEPOINT, ByVal nBufPoints As Integer, ByVal resolution As Long) As Integer
Private Sub Test1()
  SwapMouseButton False 'True|False
End Sub
Private Sub Test2()
  SetDoubleClickTime 0 '0=default(500), 48~=fastest I could get, >5000=5000
End Sub
Private Sub Test3()
  Dim hwnd As Long, mmp As MOUSEMOVEPOINT, mmpBuf(64) As MOUSEMOVEPOINT, returnedValue As Integer
  Sleep 1000
  hwnd = GetActiveWindow()
  'WindowProc hwnd, WS_MOUSEMOVE, WS_MOUSEMOVE, WS_MOUSEMOVE
  mmp.x = 600
  mmp.y = 300
  mmp.time = 200
  returnedValue = GetMouseMovePointsEx(Len(mmp), mmp, mmpBuf, 1000, 1)
  If returnedValue = -1 Then
    Debug.Print "Error"
  Else
    Debug.Print mmpBuf(0).x
    Debug.Print mmpBuf(0).y
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: 1- If you want portability, plan to include declarations for both VBA7 and WIN64 versions.
2- There is tools existing to help you translate the API calls, use them (for example [Excel API Viewer](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm) from Ron de Bruin).

Comment: @VincentG I guess that's a way to learn. Will check that out.

Comment: It seems that this particular api call is missing from the database (no idea why)

Comment: @VincentG I'm also currently using a 32-bit Windows computer so can't install it.

Comment: Shouldn't pose a problem if you downloaded the x86 version and not the x64 one.

Comment: @VincentG Okay. I wasn't sure which one to pick.